# I need to use pyodbc module so that I can connect to SQL-server but I can't use the SQL-SERVER driver

Tags: python, sql-server, dockerfile, pyodbc, alpine-linux

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
 
WORKDIR /code

RUN echo America/Montevideo > /etc/timezone
RUN echo America/Montevideo > /etc/localtime
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Montevideo /etc/localtime && echo America/Montevideo > /etc/timezone
RUN apk add curl build-base unixodbc-dev unixodbc freetds-dev && pip install pyodbc==4.0.30 && pip install elasticsearch && pip install python-dateutil && pip install pytz && pip install six && pip install urllib3 && pip install pandas && pip install numpy
RUN apk add --update tzdata

RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY app/ .
 
CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ]
```

#### app.py

```
driver = '/usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so'

conn = podbc.connect(f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={globales.SERVER};PORT={globales.PORT};DATABASE={globales.DATABASE};UID={globales.USERNAME};PWD={globales.PASSWORD};')
            
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

I can't use the method `executemany` with this approach. I'm trying to build my dockerfile so that I can use a better driver and then deploy it to openshift so that it can insert really fast documents in my database.

How can I build this dockerfile? I can use any Python images.

Locally because I'm using Windows I can use {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server} and the `executemany` works perfectly.

Comment: The release notes for msodbcsql17 say that support for Alpine Linux was added a year ago in [version 17.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/release-notes-odbc-sql-server-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15#175-january-2020).

Comment: The installation instructions are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15  You just need to integrate them into your docker file.